# how to include data-fancybox in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have bought a bootstrap template to include in my rails app. I have these lines that i would like to translate in ruby :

`<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="../assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-big-02.jpg"><img class="img-fluid w-100" src="../assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-02.jpg" alt="Image 02" /></a>`

So far I have :

`<%= image_tag('portfolio/portfolio-02.jpg', class:'img-fluid w-100', data: {fancybox: 'gallery'}) %>`

But the picture disappears after I click on it. Does anyone know the solution?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to convert an anchor tag to an image tag. I don't think that's what you really want.

You could keep the original line and only change the href and src values to link to the correct location of the file. Something like:

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/portfolio/portfolio-big-02.jpg"><img class="img-fluid w-100" src="/img/portfolio/portfolio-02.jpg" alt="Image 02" /></a>
```

This only requires you to have a folder img with the images in your public folder.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you accept the answer since it solved your problem, thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

Using ruby helpers, this:

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="../assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-big-02.jpg"><img class="img-fluid w-100" src="../assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-02.jpg" alt="Image 02" /></a>
```

would be:

```
<%= link_to image_path('portfolio/portfolio-big-02.jpg', data: {fancybox: 'gallery'} do %>
  <%= image_tag 'portfolio/portfolio-big-02.jpg', class: 'img-fluid w-100', alt: 'Image 02' %>
<% end %>
```